# How to receive Word 2010 Events with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, office-interop

I have written this simple script in order to connect to Word 2010 events. The registration works fine, but I don't receive any events.

```
$w = new-object -com "word.application"
$w.visible = $true
$ds = $w.documents
$d = $ds.add()
$action = {
    Write-Host "Changed"
}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $w -EventName DocumentChange -Action $action
```

Comment: Hi, 
Just tested will Word 2010 on Windows 8. I am getting the notified from the above code for the following events:
1] When a new document is created, 
2] When an existing document is opened, 
3] When another document is made the active document.
What version of PS are you using? And can you retrieve the registration using get-event?

Comment: You're right! I also receive only an event after opening or closing a document. I tested the same in C#. Word doesn't seem to send events, when you type in new text.

Comment: Check the following link for a full list of Word Application Events. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.application_events(v=office.14).aspx
Could see one for text entry I'm afraid.